# make calling bison -y without being asked to

Tags: makefile, yacc, bison, lex

I have a grammar I'm writing, called `portugol`. The files names are basic, but I chose to call my c program `portugol.c`.

So, basically, I have to do:

```
flex portugol.l      ==> lex.yy.c
bison -dy portugol.y ==> y.tab.c and y.tab.h
gcc y.tab.c lex.yy.c portugol.c -o portugol.bin -lm -ly  ==> portugol.bin
```

(I also have portugol.h, but it is irrelevant to the problem)

For long time now, I'm using a shell script I called `flexyagcc.sh` that do this. No error in the process.

So now I decided to learn `makefile`.

The problem I'm facing is that for some odd reason, "`bison -dy`" I called is followed by this command I didn't write: `mv -f y.tab.c portugol.c`

Well, this destroys my handmade source file!

I've tried all I could, but could not get rid of this "`mv`".

I even did a `sleep` and tried:

```
y.tab.c y.tab.h : portugol.y
    @echo --- bison -----------------------------------------------
    mv -f portugol.c ptg.c
    $(BISON) $(BFLAGS) portugol.y
    @echo --- bison sleeping --------------------------------------
    sleep 5
    -mv -f portugol.c y.tab.c
    -mv -f ptg.c portugol.c
```

But for my surprise, I got the following events (in this order):

```
$ make all o=pequeno
--- bison -----------------------------------------------
mv -f portugol.c ptg.c
bison -dy portugol.y
--- bison sleeping --------------------------------------
sleep 5
mv -f portugol.c y.tab.c
mv: cannot stat `portugol.c': No such file or directory
make: [y.tab.c] Error 1 (ignored)
mv -f ptg.c portugol.c
bison -dy portugol.y 
mv -f y.tab.c portugol.c
```

Surprise! The `mv` command is the last one! No matter what I do. I created other rules, just to make it happen last (or first to trick the recursive process). No way! I also used the directive: `.NOTPARALLEL.` No way.

I also tried all in the same line, to be sure they execute in the given order:

```
mv -f portugol.c ptg.c && $(BISON) $(BFLAGS) portugol.y && sleep 5 && mv -f portugol.c y.tab.c && mv -f ptg.c portugol.c
```

No success.

Well, before I gave up, I decided to use the standard bison output. So, I would have:

```
flex portugol.l         ==> lex.yy.c
bison -d portugol.y     ==> portugol.tab.c and y.tab.h
gcc portugol.tab.c lex.yy.c portugol.c -o portugol.bin -lm -ly  ==> portugol.bin
```

But I still get this:

```
--- bison -----------------------------------------------
bison -d portugol.y
bison -y portugol.y 
mv -f y.tab.c portugol.c
```

I also tried to `chmod -w` before and `+w` after bison, no way.

For now, I run out of ideas.

Is there a way to prevent make to call the second bison? Or to call the `mv` command? Or to trick it to not overwrite my file `portugol.c`?

Thanks!
Beco

PS- Edited. Using:

```
 Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS
 GNU Make 3.81
```

PPS. Edited. Minor typos.

PPPS. Edited. Answering Ise wisteria:

Thanks for your answer. I've saved your makefile as makefile2 and tried. The answer I got from the make is:

```
$ make -f makefile2
bison -dy portugol.y
yacc  portugol.y 
mv -f y.tab.c portugol.c
gcc y.tab.c lex.yy.c portugol.c -o portugol.bin -lm -ly
gcc: y.tab.c: No such file or directory
make: *** [portugol.bin] Error 1
```

I also noted that "today" the second bison call is not a bison call, but a yacc call. Maybe we are talking about some environment variable here? It also changes with my makefile:

```
$ make all o=pequeno
--- bison -----------------------------------------------
bison --defines=y.tab.h --output=y.tab.c portugol.y
--- flex ------------------------------------------------
flex  portugol.l
yacc  portugol.y 
mv -f y.tab.c portugol.c
```

PPPPS. Answering Beta. Your advice works. I called make y.tab.c and got a simple:

```
$ make y.tab.c
--- bison -----------------------------------------------
bison --defines=y.tab.h --output=y.tab.c portugol.y
$
```

Here is my complete makefile:

```
# Compila o compilador Portugol usando lex e yacc,
# e opcionalmente gera o .asm.c e o .bin
# a partir do fonte .ptg usando o novo compilador gerado.
#
#/*
#    arquivo: makefile
#    Autor: Ruben Carlo Benante
#    Email: ***@beco.cc
#    Data: 23/04/2009
#    Modificado: 22/03/2011
#    Versao: Portugol v3q
#*/
#
# Exemplo:
# ./flexyagcc portugol teste
#
# inicia os seguintes processos:
#      flex portugol.l                                          (gera lex.yy.c)
#      bison -dy portugol.y                                     (gera yy.tab.c e yy.tab.h)
#      gcc y.tab.c lex.yy.c portugol.c -o portugol.bin -lm -ly  (gera portugol.bin)
#
# inicia opcionalmente (ultimas linhas descomentadas):
#      portugol.bin teste.ptg teste.asm.c                (gera teste.asm.c)
#      gcc -x c teste.asm.c -o teste.bin -lm             (gera teste.bin)
#
#
# entrada:
#          portugol.l (arquivo em linguagem lex, analisador lexico)
#          portugol.y (arquivo em linguagem yacc, analisador sintatico)
#          portugol.c (arquivo em linguagem c, gerador de codigo)
# entrada opcional:
#          teste.ptg  (arquivo em linguagem portugol)
#
# saida:
#        lex.yy.c (saida do lex, em linguagem c)
#        y.tab.c  (saida do yacc, em linguagem c)
#        y.tab.h  (saida do yacc, definicoes da linguagem portugol)
#        portugol.bin (saida do gcc, arquivo executavel, finalmente o compilador portugol)
# saida opcional:
#        teste.asm.c   (saida do compilador portugol, arquivo em codigo de quadruplas)
#        teste.bin     (saida do gcc, arquivo executavel, o fonte .ptg em binario)
#
###################################### 
LEX     = flex
BISON = bison
BFLAGS  = --defines=y.tab.h --output=y.tab.c
CC = gcc
#CFLAGS = -g0 -O3 -Wall
CFLAGS = -g0
OBJS = y.tab.o lex.yy.o portugol.o
#OBJS = portugol.tab.o lex.yy.o portugol.o
DEPS =  portugol.h y.tab.h
SOURCES = y.tab.c lex.yy.c portugol.c
#SOURCES = portugol.tab.c lex.yy.c portugol.c

.PHONY : clean cleanall cleanptg run all makebug teste

.NOTPARALLEL :

#portugol.bin : lex.yy.c y.tab.c y.tab.h portugol.c portugol.h
portugol.bin : $(SOURCES) $(DEPS) $(OBJS)
    @echo --- gcc portugol ----------------------------------------
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o portugol.bin -lm -ly
#   gcc lex.yy.c y.tab.c portugol.c -o portugol.bin -lm -ly
#   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCES) -o portugol.bin -lm -ly

%.o : %.c
    @echo --- gcc objects -----------------------------------------
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

#portugol.tab.c y.tab.h : portugol.y
y.tab.c y.tab.h : portugol.y
    @echo --- bison -----------------------------------------------
    $(BISON) $(BFLAGS) portugol.y
#   @echo --- bison y.tab.c ---------------------------------------
#   mv -f portugol.c ptg.c
#   sleep 3
#   -mv -f portugol.c y.tab.c
#   -mv -f ptg.c portugol.c

lex.yy.c : portugol.l
    @echo --- flex ------------------------------------------------
    $(LEX) $(LFLAGS) portugol.l

teste :
    @echo --- testing ---------------------------------------------
    @echo $(o)

#Portugol -----------

%.asm.c : %.ptg portugol.bin
    @echo --- portugol --------------------------------------------
    ./portugol.bin $< $@

%.bin : %.asm.c
    @echo --- gcc asm ---------------------------------------------
    $(CC) -x c $< -o $@ -lm

run : $(o).bin
    @echo --- running! --------------------------------------------
    ./$(o).bin

all : $(o).bin

clean:
    -rm lex.yy.c y.tab.c y.tab.h *.o portugol.bin portugol.tab.c

cleanall:
    -rm lex.yy.c y.tab.c y.tab.h *.o *.bin

cleanasm:
    -rm *.asm.c
```

VPS. Important edit update. Attention for a possible indication of the real problem:

I changed the name `portugol.y` to `portugol.syn` and the problem has stoped!

```
--- bison -----------------------------------------------
bison --defines=y.tab.h --output=y.tab.c portugol.syn
---------------------------------------------------------
```

How is that? This indicates, in my opinion, that make has some default evaluation for files ".y" and now we need, to answer this question, to find out the root of this, and how to disable it. Thanks very much.

Comment: Could you try `make y.tab.c` instead of `make all o=pequeno`?

Comment: Dear Beta, your advice works! I would like to vote a positive value to your answering, but you added a comment. If you please can elaborate this I'm sure we are in the way of finding out the problem. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, but I made only a small suggestion, to simplify the build and isolate the problem. Chris Dodd found the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that make has built-in rules for building .c files from .y and .l files, and it is these builtin rules that are getting triggered and causing you grief.

With GNU make, you can disable these builtin rules by overriding them with blank rules.  Put

```
%.c: %.y
%.c: %.l
```

in your makefile somewhere and your problems should go away.

You can see all of GNU make's built-in rules by running `make -p -f /dev/null`

Comment: Thanks Chris! That definitively solved the case! :) The build in is exactly this: `%.c: %.y \
#  commands to execute (built-in): \
        $(YACC.y) $<  \
        mv -f y.tab.c $@ \ ` The `mv` I was talking about showed itself up in the `make -p -f /dev/null` you told. Thanks!

Comment: Chris, after understanding the core of the problem, I thought another possible solution was to let the buit-in works, and do completely delete the rules I wrote for bison. But that led me to: `$ make all o=pequeno
make: *** No rule to make target `y.tab.c', needed by `portugol.bin'.  Stop.`

Comment: @Dr Beco, if you remove your rule for `y.tab.c`, make fails, because the implicit rule knows only how to make `y.tab.c` from `y.tab.y`. It cannot know that you want `y.tab.c` to be made from `portugol.y`.

Comment: If you want to use the builtin rules, you need to follow Jonathan Leffler's suggestion of renaming the files, as the builtin rule wants to create a .c file with the same base name as the .y

Answer (score 2):

Basically, do not try to fight the system.  You need to be able to create `portugol.o` - and have three possible source files: `portugol.l`, `portugol.y`, `portugol.c`.  That is at least two too many.

Make sure that the basenames of the source files (minus the extension) are unique.  For example, use `portugoll.l`, `portugoly.y`, and `portugol.c`, with object files `portugoll.o`, `portugoly.o` and `portugol.o`.  Or use longer suffixes - `portugol-lex.l`, `portugol-yacc.y`.  Or `portlex.l`, `portyacc.y`, or ...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jonathan,

So you see the one solution I've also perceived: change the name of the file. But, well, that is the point of the question. I have no problems using the script. If I call `bison -dy portugol.y` from the shell script `flexyagcc.sh` it gives me `y.tab.c` and `y.tab.h`. Why not from a `makefile`, that is the central point!

I do like my file names, it makes all so coherent: `portugol.c`: handmade routines, `portugol.h`:header file, `portugol.l`:lex scanner, and `portugol.y`: parser. Also, this is not a project I made today, it has being like that for years now, lots of versions (now 3.0). So, it is not an option to change the file names. Beside that, I would end up with `portugol.c` anyway! But it would be a file automatically generated from bison, aka `y.tab.c`. So, it is very confusing to stop using `portugol.c` to have handmade routines, and start using the same name to have the parser.

I just want to know what is happening with makefile, and how can I use it to substitute the script the way it is. While I can't, unfortunately, I'll be using the script. The script is very simple:

```
flex portugol.l
bison -dy portugol.y
gcc y.tab.c lex.yy.c portugol.c -o portugol.bin -lm -ly
```

See, I don't even bother to have the objectives `portugol.o`, `y.tab.o` and `lex.yy.o`. I skip creating them by just running the `gcc` on the sources directly. I also can do this in the makefile, if after the first attempt to destroy my `portugol.c`, I rename manually the file created to be `y.tab.c`.

So the problem is that makefile differs from the above script by attempting to create the following:

- lex the same: `portugol.l` for both cases (script and makefile)
- bison: automagically changed from `y.tab.c` to `portugol.c` (here the problem!)
- c code: I would need to change `portugol.c` to something else, like `portugol-funcs.c`

Thanks for your kind attention!
Beco

Comment: StackOverflow is a question and answer site, not a forum.  This space is reserved for answers, and what you've posted here is not really an answer. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Thanks, Robert. I saw that some time after I get used to the site. It was new for me. I realize after I saw the "accept answer" button. This answer of mine should be part of the question (maybe a edit). Now, what should we (or I) do? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: It's too long to go into an (already long) question, so we'll just leave this one here.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, as far as I tested with small improvised files, the problem you
mentioned didn't occur.
My `make`'s version is GNU 3.80.
For your information, the following is the `makefile` I used.

```
portugol.bin: y.tab.c lex.yy.c portugol.c
        gcc $^ -o $@ -lm -ly

y.tab.c: portugol.y
        bison -dy $<

lex.yy.c: portugol.l
        flex $<
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Dear Ise, thanks! I just tried your makefile. The output I got is: $ make -f makefile2 \
bison -dy portugol.y \
yacc  portugol.y  \
mv -f y.tab.c portugol.c \
gcc y.tab.c lex.yy.c portugol.c -o portugol.bin -lm -ly \
gcc: y.tab.c: No such file or directory \
make: *** [portugol.bin] Error 1 \ Sorry, I'll put it in a formated answer.