# Why doesn't make build an object file on the first run?

Tags: makefile, target

I have [this Makefile](https://github.com/theory/flex-lemon-example/blob/master/Makefile):

```
CFLAGS := $(CFLAGS) -std=c99

shell: main.o shellparser.o shellscanner.o
    $(CC) -o shell main.o shellparser.o shellscanner.o

main.o: main.c shellparser.h shellscanner.h

shellparser.o: shellparser.h

shellparser.h: shellparser.y lemon
    ./lemon shellparser.y

shellscanner.o: shellscanner.h

shellscanner.h: shellscanner.l
    flex --outfile=shellscanner.c --header-file=shellscanner.h shellscanner.l

# Prevent yacc from trying to build parsers.
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/5395195/79202
%.c: %.y

lemon: lemon.c
    $(CC) -o lemon lemon.c
```

For some reason, on the first run of `make`, `shellparser.o` isn't built:

```
> make
cc -o lemon lemon.c
./lemon shellparser.y
flex --outfile=shellscanner.c --header-file=shellscanner.h shellscanner.l
cc  -std=c99   -c -o main.o main.c
cc  -std=c99   -c -o shellscanner.o shellscanner.c
cc -o shell main.o shellparser.o shellscanner.o
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: shellparser.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [shell] Error 1
rm shellscanner.c
```

If I run it again, it then builds it correctly:

```
> make
cc  -std=c99   -c -o shellparser.o shellparser.c
cc -o shell main.o shellparser.o shellscanner.o
```

So what do I have out-of-order such that it doesn't build it the first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you try to build, Make doesn’t know that `lemon` outputs `shellparser.c`, so it doesn’t try to build it. When you rebuild, `shellparser.c` does exist, so Make uses it. The solution is to explicitly tell Make that `lemon` outputs `shellparser.c`:

```
diff --git a/Makefile b/Makefile
index bf2655e..d6b288d 100644
--- a/Makefile
+++ b/Makefile
@@ -7,7 +7,7 @@ main.o: main.c shellparser.h shellscanner.h

 shellparser.o: shellparser.h

-shellparser.h: shellparser.y lemon
+shellparser.c shellparser.h: shellparser.y lemon
        ./lemon shellparser.y

 shellscanner.o: shellscanner.h
diff --git a/main.c b/main.c
index 81ec151..4179981 100644
--- a/main.c
+++ b/main.c
@@ -33,7 +33,7 @@ void parse(const char *commandLine) {
 }

 // Borrowed from http://stackoverflow.com/a/314422/79202.
-char * getline(void) {
+char * my_getline(void) {
     char * line = malloc(100), * linep = line;
     size_t lenmax = 100, len = lenmax;
     int c;
@@ -69,7 +69,7 @@ int main(int argc, char** argv) {
     void* shellParser = ParseAlloc(malloc);
     char *line;
     printf("> ");
-    while ( line = getline() ) {
+    while ( line = my_getline() ) {
         parse(line);
         printf("> ");
     }
```

Also I renamed `getline` so it would build on my mac; thanks for posting all your source!

Comment: Awesome, I just figured this out myself and pushed the fix, then found your answer when I came back to answer it. Thanks!

Comment: Also [renamed `getline()` to `get_stdin_line()`](https://github.com/theory/flex-lemon-example/commit/d8ab8de07b5079fa9bdf2393f551dbf03650a4af). Thanks for pointing that out. For some odd reason, `getline()` is not defined on my Mac (OS X Mountain Lion).

Comment: Huh—I’m on Mountain Lion but it’s flagged `__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7)` in [stdio.h](http://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-825.25/include/stdio.h).

Comment: Maybe because I upgraded from Lion? My `/usr/include/stdio.h` doesn't have `getline`, though `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h` has it.